# Error message with store provider's data reader when adding table to new EF model

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm adding some new tables to my EF model and I am seeing this error now:

I ran this line of code:

`SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT 40000`

and it still fails and gives me the error below. What could this issue be?

I've deleted the new tables, upgraded to EF 6.2, and tried to clear out the entire model and re-add the entire thing and I still get this error. The database is hosted via a hosting service provider.

**UPDATE:** 
**I contact my hosting site admin and they stated they couldn't change this value due to performance issues. They said take a backup of my database to a local SQL server and then update it there and restore back to their hosting site. I'm still confused though - do I have a bad table that is causing this issue?**

> Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The query has been canceled because the estimated cost of this query (4212) exceeds the configured threshold of 3000. Contact the system administrator.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.HandleReaderException(Exception e)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.ResultAssembly.BridgeDataReader.SetShaper(Shaper`1 shaper, CoordinatorFactory`1 coordinatorFactory, Int32 depth)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.ResultAssembly.BridgeDataReader.<>c__DisplayClass4.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.ResultAssembly.BridgeDataReader.EnsureInitialized()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.ResultAssembly.BridgeDataReader.Read()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityDataReader.Read()
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadDataTable[T](String sql, Func`2 orderByFunc, DataTable table, EntityStoreSchemaFilterObjectTypes queryTypes, IEnumerable`1 filters, String[] filterAliases)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadRelationships(IEnumerable`1 filters)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadStoreSchemaDetails(IList`1 filters)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GetStoreSchemaDetails(StoreSchemaConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.CreateStoreModel()
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GenerateModel(List`1 errors)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModels(String storeModelNamespace, ModelBuilderSettings settings, List`1 errors)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModel(ModelBuilderSettings settings, IVsUtils vsUtils, ModelBuilderEngineHostContext hostContext)'.
>   Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:02.2571511.
>   Generating the model took 00:00:09.6555569.

Comment: Are you trying to add a very complex view to EF? Does it start failing always with the same new object mapping? The server is rejecting your request because it's estimate of processing it is too high, which shouldn't be the case when querying simple metadata of objects (what EF does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT 40000` just sets the limit for the current connection (e.g. just the one SSMS session). All other calls from VS be it runtime or design time will not be affected this way.

If you are the DB admin (or have sufficient rights) then use [sp_configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-query-governor-cost-limit-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017). Otherwise you will need to contact the server admin.

Comment: I contacted my hosting site admin and they stated they couldn't change this value due to performance issues. They said take a backup of my database to a local SQL server and then update it there and restore back to their hosting site. I'm still confused though - do I have a bad table that is causing this issue?

Comment: I backed up my database and restore locally to SQL server and manually changed the QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT property.  Then the model loaded without any issues.

I suppose I have a table that is causing an issue?

Comment: @tvb108108: unfortunately I don't have experience with this type of error. You could try using SQL Profiler for your local DB and try to find out what query could be the exact cause of the problem. On the other hand - as the limit is in seconds - it is really suspicious that a query has an estimated cost over 1 hour.